# What is the scaling behind PIL.Image.fromarray method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

Say I have an a numpy array with a range of values between -14 and 4450.

[image]

[image]

If I convert that numpy array into a `PIL Image` it gets automagically scaled between 0 and 255.

[image]

I'm digging through the source code of `fromarray` [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L2715) but I can't seem to find any hints as to how the scaling works. Can someone please explain to me how `fromarray` scales numbers behind the scenes?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no scaling involved here, because you already type cast the original NumPy array by passing `arr.astype(np.uint8)` to `Image.fromarray`!

Let's investigate that issue:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr = np.random.rand(1000, 1000) * 4464 - 14
print('Original array: ', arr.min(), arr.max(), '\n')

arr2 = arr.astype(np.uint8)
print('Intermediate NumPy array: ', arr2.min(), arr2.max(), '\n')

im = Image.fromarray(arr)
print('Correct PIL.Image array: ', np.array(im).min(), np.array(im).max())
print('PIL.Image format: ', im.mode)
```

That'd be the outputs:

```
Original array:  -13.993518056270652 4449.9957434693215 

Intermediate NumPy array:  0 255 

Correct PIL.Image array:  -13.993518 4449.9956
PIL.Image format:  F
```

As you can see, the `min` and `max` of the intermediate NumPy array `arr2` are already `0` and `255`. Notice: Type casting from `float` to `np.uint8` doesn't involve scaling, you just have rounding and integer underflows and overflows.

If you pass the original NumPy array `arr` to `Image.fromarray`, the `min` and `max` of the `PIL.Image` object `im` are still something like `-14` and `4450`. Also, the [image mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) is `F` for float.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
NumPy:       1.19.4
Pillow:      8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: TIL I learned about integer underflows and overflows.  Thanks @HansHirse!